# If the sum of two functions is continuous at a point, can one function be continuous and the other not

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I got this question:

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions such that $f+g$ is continuous at $a$, Must it be the case that both $f$ and $g$ are continuous at $a$ or that both $f$ and $g$ are  discontinuous at $a$, 
In other words, Can we find two functions such that $f$ is continuous at $a$ and $g$ is discontinuous at $a$ but their sum $f+g$ is continuous at $a$?

I tried to prove it and to find a counter example but so far I failed.

Comment: $f  = (f + g) - g$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that f is continuous and h = f + g where h is continuous. Then g = h - f and as the difference of two continuous functions is continuous then g is continuous. I.e. if one function is continuous then the other must be too, so you can't have one continuous and one not.

As in previous answer if g is discontinuous then so is -g but h = g + -g = 0 is continuous.

Comment: Yes. Thanks....

Comment: But now what about product?  If $F$ is continuous and $FG$ is continuous, does it follow that $G$ is continuous?

Comment: No. Because take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=sin x / x $ then $(fg)(x) = sin x$ which is continuous at $0$ and also $f$ is continuous at $0$ but $g(x)$ is not continuous at $0$ since $g(0)$ is not defined.